# PHP mysql update row where user id will be same

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, php-5.3

i want to insert the value in table first time once i did that again only update in same row and not insert again.  my user id is unique

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate question. When asking questions please take a look and see if the question you want to ask has already been asked before.

Comment: convert your necessary column into `primary key` to update on duplicate & insert on new. Might be duplicate as @Kael. Just post your code in detail

Comment: convet the user id as primary key and use on duplicate key query